# Hibernate raw queries not parsing '\N' in WHERE clause

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I wanted to run a simple raw query through hibernate. Something like

`SELECT * FROM table where column = '\N'`

This query runs fine in via MySQL but does not execute through hibernate.

The background behind why '\N' and not null is that, for some reason while ingesting data from Hadoop into MySQL the null transforms into '\N'.

I have tried various different ways of doing the query like escaping escapes etc. None of them work. So right now I have put in a cron which changes all the \N into null regularly.

```
String queryString =
        String.format(
            QUERY_PLACE_HOLDER_CATEGORY_AVERAGE,
            "new MetricsCategoryAverage("
                + getProjections(queryParameter.getSelectColumns())
                + ")",
            !isSignup ? "and aspse.liveDate != '\\N'" : "",
            "de.date >= :from_date and de.date <= :to_date ",
            getGroupBy(queryParameter.getGroupByColumns()));

    Query<MetricsCategoryAverage> query =
        session.createQuery(queryString, MetricsCategoryAverage.class);

    query.setParameter("from_date", fromDate);
    query.setParameter("to_date", toDate);
    query.setParameter("category", category);

    return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: You should not construct your query like that, you're kisking SQL Injection. 
By the way for your problem, considère using `String::replace`.

Comment: What is the current error output and/or result set?

Comment: I will say create criteria and do something like that

Criteria criteria ...

criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(theInputString+" /n")

Comment: I am still in doubt if "/n" is now varchar or string. I feel it is still null. I have a solution for that as well if you confirm.

Comment: @KunalVohra it was DATE in the table, right now its varchar(was trying out different solutions).

Comment: @Zorglube No chances of SQL injections. The code I posted is many many layers down the UI. Also its behind a auth layer. So a person can only see his own data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there is no error as such. Just that the query doesn't return any result

Comment: Did you try logging your hibernate query (what query hibernate is actually sending to database)? On a different note - SQL injection is not only about unauthorised people accessing data, but also about authorised person injecting code to access unauthorised data. You know your application better, but an example would be I am trying to modify someone else's stackoverflow's profile.